# Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

Following is my code:

```
      <Routes>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={(props) => (
              <Fragment>
                <Search
                  searchUsers={this.searchUsers}
                  clearUsers={this.clearUsers}
                  showClear={users.length > 0 ? true : false}
                  setAlert={this.setAlert}
                />
                <Users loading={loading} users={users} />
              </Fragment>
            )}
          />
      </Routes>
```

I am expecting to have the home page working as it was working without react router dom but as I implemented it, it shows a empty page.

Comment: Please provide stackblitz or codesandbox link if you can as we need to know where and how you are using router

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/prabal-goyal/GITHUB_FINDER/main?workspaceId=dbf1e6f1-8d1d-48e5-8b2c-c2965293a815

Answer (score 0):

There is difference in v6 and v5 of react router dom. You seem to be mixing them up.

V5:
`Switch` is used with `render` prop.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={(props) => (
          <Fragment>
            <Search
              searchUsers={this.searchUsers}
              clearUsers={this.clearUsers}
              showClear={users.length > 0 ? true : false}
              setAlert={this.setAlert}
            />
            <Users loading={loading} users={users} />
          </Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

v6:
`Routes` is used with `element` prop.

```
<Router>
   <Routes>
     <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          <Fragment>
            <Search
              searchUsers={this.searchUsers}
              clearUsers={this.clearUsers}
              showClear={users.length > 0 ? true : false}
              setAlert={this.setAlert}
            />
            <Users loading={loading} users={users} />
          </Fragment>
        }
      />
   </Routes>
 </Router>
```